# Need help choosing loss function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I have used resnet50 to solve a multi-class classification problem. The model outputs probabilities for each class. Which loss function should I choose for my model?

After choosing binary cross entropy :
[image]

After choosing categorical cross entropy:
[image]

The above results are for the same model with just different loss functions.This model is supposed to classify images into 26 classes so categorical cross entropy should work.
Also, in the first case accuracy is about 96% but losses are so high. Why?

edit 2:
Model architecture:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you give us more insights on your data and the code you are using?
Namely how many images are you working with (training and validation)? Are you using a pre-trained resnet50 and just fine-tuning the last layers?

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) how to create the perfect minimal working example.

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi Uploaded insights on data and code in edit.

Comment: Next time try to copy-paste the code. It's much more efficient for us. Right now to help you, I have to rewrite it line-by-line each time coming back to this tab.

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi Apologies for that.Refer to the file named resnet50dropout5.ipynb to train model in the given Github link : https://github.com/JasmineGhumman/SignLanguageDetection/blob/master/resnet50dropout5.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to use `categorical_crossentropy` for a multi-classification problem. `binary_crossentropy` will reduce your problem down to a binary classification problem in a way that's unclear without further looking into it.

I would say that the reason you are seeing high accuracy in the first (and to some extent the second) case is because you are overfitting. The first dense layer you are adding contains 8 million parameters (!!! to see that do `model.summary()`), and you only have 70k images to train it with 8 epochs. This architectural choice is very demanding both in computing power and in data requirement. You are also using a very basic optimizer (`SGD`). Try to use a more powerful [`Adam`](https://keras.io/optimizers/#Adam).

Finally, I am a bit surprised at your choice to take a `'sigmoid'` activation function in the output layer. Why not a more classic `'softmax'`?

Comment: No probs. If it solves your problem, make sure to [upvote and accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;)

Comment: 8 million parameters and 70k images, thanks for bringing that up.Anything that you could recommend about fixing that? Apart from this, will use Adam and softmax. Hope making all these changes together would improve the overfitting situation.Thanks!

Comment: Or would you recommend using some other architecture? Which can work better for this size of dataset?

Comment: I would definitely recommend starting with a simpler architecture if you haven't already done that (like vgg or even alexnet).

Answer (score 1):

For a multi-class classification problem you use the `categorical_crossentropy` loss, as what it does is match the ground truth probability distribution with the one predicted by the model.

This is exactly what is used for multi-class classification, you have a misconception of you think you can't use this loss.

Comment: Categorical cross entropy ain't working. Could you check out the edit and give a possible fix/reason?

Comment: @Jasmine No, not really, the loss isn't the problem, your model is overfitting, you have to find out why.

Comment: I'm not sure which way to look.One thing I found fishy,besides the overfitting problem ofcourse,  was that binary entropy was working more sensibly than categorical entropy, even though it ain't binary classification.